# Importing pandas breaks my os.walk loop

Tags: python, pandas

I just found out about pandas and installed buy now my loop iterating through files behaves strangely. Here's a minimal example that has the issue for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

PATH=os.environ['HOME']+"/scripts/"

for path_, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(PATH):
  for name in file_names:
    print(path_+name)
```

As I have only a singe file (i.e. this script) in the folder the output is as expected:

```
/home/scripts/parser.py
```

However if I now extend `import os` with `pandas` (`import os, pandas`) the file is printed twice:

```
/home/scripts/parser.py
/home/scripts/parser.py
```

I have no idea what is going on here. Did I somehow mess up the installation (apt-get install python3-pandas)?

**EDIT:**

I don't know if this is related but when I import pandas a `__pycache__` folder is generated.

Comment: If you accidently named your script pandas.py or if you accidently typed "import os, parser" instead of "import os, pandas", this is the behavior that you'd see. It would be really weird if this is really caused by pandas.

Comment: I can verify that I used the correct naming. I also created several new folders just to test it and it was always the same. And since I too don't think its caused by pandas itself I thought may be related to how I installed it.

Comment: If you name the script something completely different, do you get the same result?

Comment: Wow, this worked OO so basically it was due to the file name ```parser.py```. If you answer this question (maybe with an explanation) I will accept it. Thanks alot.

Comment: I bet you have $HOME/scripts in your PYTHONPATH. Is that true?

Comment: I dont think so. I didnt set anything specifically, also as said I created several other folders in other directories showing the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a generic Python thing. This script will replicate the problem without pandas:

parser.py:

```
import tempfile
print 'hello'
```

Where tempfile is a standard python package.

Now run in bash

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=.
$ python parser.py
hello
hello
```

The print statement gets executed twice! What happens is that parser.py imports tempfile, and tempfile tries to import the standard python package "parser" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html). But since "." (the current directory) is in the PYTHONPATH, it instead imports the original script again, which prints "hello" an extra time.

Moral of the story: don't name your scripts the same thing as a standard library package, and definitely don't mess around with PYTHONPATH.